# Calculate field with Null values

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro

I am trying to add to rows using the *calculate fields*.

[image]

An error message appears stating that my expression

```
!base_co_p! + !base_co_j!
```

[image]

has some null values, hence it cannot proceed with the addition.

How can I change my expressions as seen below so that it:

1. It adds row-wise
2. If ever there is a  observation, ignore it and treat it and treat it as a zero?

I am familiar with python, but do not know how to implement it with ArcGIS pro.

Comment: Have you tried using "if"-statements to catch the errors?

Comment: I still haven't tried this. How do I go on by using python with the field calculator?

Comment: Can't help you with the specific language, only with the general concept, since I work with QGIS.

Comment: Simplest solution is so "Select by attributes" rows that are None, then Field calculate them to 0. Then your code should work. Or try: (`!base_co_p! or 0) + (!base_co_j! or 0)`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978738/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator . (I have not tried it in an expression like the screenshot you show though)

Comment: I agree with @BERA, the simplest is to select rows that have no null data and then run your field calculate, as it will honour selections only they get processed.